# Are there any statements $\phi$ where "$\vdash \phi$ or $\vdash \neg \phi$" was shown nonconstructively?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, proof-theory

I am wondering if there is an example of a statement $\phi$ in the language of some formal system $T$ satisfying (1-4):

1. $\phi$ was shown to *not* be independent of $T$ (i.e. it was proved that $T \vdash \phi$ or $T \vdash \neg \phi$)
2. The proof in (1) was nonconstructive: it was initially (or still) unknown which of {$\phi, \neg \phi$} was a theorem of $T$.
3. $\phi$ was not clearly $\Delta_0$ (any bounded statement like "there is no odd perfect number less than 10↑↑↑10" has a (possibly long) proof/disproof).
4. $\phi$ was *not* part of some class of statements $C$ that were shown by some algorithm to be decidable. (For instance, any statement in Presburger arithmetic or ACF/RCF which we know to be decidable by a quantifier elimination algorithm).
5. $T$ is r.e.

Comment: As stated, the answer is yes and here's a rather silly example: Let $T$ be the theory of the constructible universe $L$ (in some fixed universe $V$ such that $T$ exists) and let $\phi$ be Riemann's hypothesis. Since $T$ is complete, we have $T \vdash \phi$ or $T \vdash \neg \phi$. But we don't yet know which one it is.

Comment: Yes, I thought I forgot a non-triviality condition: $T$ should be r.e. I think that fixes that class of examples?

Comment: Not really. We know that there is a finite subtheory $T'$ of $T$ that decides Riemann's hypothesis.

Comment: Yeah, but for that finite subtheory, we know exactly which way it decides RH. We want an example of a theory $T$ where we don't know which way $T$ decides $\phi$, just that it does. Unless we have access to the theory of $L$ I don't see how to recursively enumerate any $T'$ as you've described it. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: The point is we don't know how $T'$ decides RH (only that it decides RH in the same way as $T$). And we do have access to $T$ and $T'$. The latter, being finite, is trivially r.e.

Comment: I'm not sure I can articulate this distinction well, but I'm going to claim that the statement "The latter, being finite, is trivially r.e" does not support the claim you're making: Let $BB_n$ be the first $n$ busy beaver numbers. Then for $n$ sufficiently large, we can't (really) recursively list $BB_n$. _Technically_ we can, because it's just a finite list, but we won't _know_ that this list is $BB_n$. I claim that the axioms of $T'$ are similar: yes, there's a recursive way to write down a set that's extensionally equal, but not to prove that set satisfies the definition of $T'$.

Comment: It seems to me that you may be confusing two things here. For each $n$ $BB_n$ is recursively enumerable. However, the function $n \mapsto BB_n$ is not recursive. Likewhise the set $\{BB_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ is not r.e. In any case: The example above is only meant to suggest that your question, as stated, probably isn't the question you have in mind. It may be difficult to formulate what precisely you're looking for, which I fully acknowledge. But, on the other hand, it's difficult to guess which answers may fit your intended question.